# MSBuild failing to expand environment variables

Tags: msbuild, environment-variables

I'm pretty new to MSBuild, so I might be doing something obviously-wrong, but a colleague of mine who's worked with MSBuild a lot can't see any error, so I figured I'd post here and see if anyone else can see it.

I'm converting an old batch file that we used to call `ant` to MSBuild tasks (because we want to call it from MSBuild) and the environment variables always expand to `)`for reasons we don't understand.

I have a property group that includes

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvJavaHome>
    $([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME"))
  </EnvJavaHome>
  <!-- ... -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

(line breaks added for legibility). Now the [MSBuild Property Functions reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) suggests I'm calling [System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx) correctly, but I always get a value of `)`. The code works perfectly well when I hardcode the value, however.

What obvious thing am I missing?  :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's an env variable, you should be able to just use it like `$(JAVA_HOME)`
as in `<EnvJavaHome>$(JAVA_HOME)</EnvJavaHome>` , see e.g. use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459(v=VS.100).aspx

(Check that the environment variable actually exists though, `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in a command window)

Comment: I just discovered exactly the same thing and figured I should hit reload before posting the fact.

Thank you!  :o)

Comment: Just as a warning, because it's bitten me. Visual Studio in some way caches environment variables, so when you add new system environment variable it could be still empty. Restarting VS usually helps.